# find the supremum and/or infimum of this set

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

I am struggling to find the supremum and/or infimum of this set:

$$ S = \biggl\{ \frac{x^2+y^2}{xy} \;\bigg|\; x>0, y>0 \biggr\}$$

any kind of help will really be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: Write each element of this set as:
$$
\frac{x^2+y^2}{xy} = \frac{x}{y} + \frac{y}{x}
$$

Put $z = \frac{x}{y}$ where $z > 0$, and study the function:
$$
f(z) = z + \frac{1}{z}
$$

Answer (score 2):

The first thing is to observe this $ (x-y)^{2} \ge 0$ Then if you rearrange what you have in your set, you have:

$ \frac{x^{2}+y^{2}}{xy} \ge 2$ And then using this you can show infimum. By using previous post you can show that there is no supremum.

Comment: Can I ask where you got (x-y)^2 from?

Comment: I am not sure I am getting your question right, but for any given number x and y I can write $(x-y)^{2}$. For your given set and elements of that set I also can do this.